# fetchRelated after fetch using Backbone.Relational with Backbone.Marionette and Backbone.ioSync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io, backbone-relational, marionette

I'm using Backbone.Relational with Backbone.Marionette and Backbone.ioSync to sync over socket.io.

More specifically, I have a model `A` that `hasMany` instances of mode `B` through relation `bees`. On load, all is well: data initialized and rendered appropriately. Then, another client adds another instance of `B` to `A.bees`. The server sends a ping to the first client, which causes it to call `A.fetch()`. In the success method of the fetch, I call `A.fetchRelated('bees')`. The fetch method returns only a list of IDs for the `bees` relation, triggering a `change` on `A`, causing Backbone.Marionatte's collection view to create a new instance of the item view to display the new `B`, which breaks the site since the new `B` hasn't been fetched yet.

Trying to force the rendering of B's view to sync on a deferred object defined in A sounds like a complex hack with likely many edge cases to handle.

One idea is to allow `fetch` to accept the `silent` option. But it's probably tricky to trigger the `change` and `add` events in the `success` function of `fetch`.

Another idea is to make the serialization code on the server *context aware* and send the entire object, not just the IDs, when a new item is added. This is also sub optimal as it may cause unnecessary transfer of entire identical B's when they're added to different A's. It also adds a lot of complexity to the server code as the context would need to propagate throughout the serialization process.

Any thoughts or suggestions of how to approach this? I am open to solutions that may require changes to Backbone.Marionette or Backbone.Relational as long as it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette now has Marionette.Async that makes it easier to execute async fetch and fetchRelated requests. Further there was is a bug in Backbone-Relational that didn't respect the `silent` option passed automatically by backbone when saving an object with `wait: true`. See the https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/pull/153 for the pull request to fix this.